# PHP ics-parser Multiple ICS Calls

Tags: php

I am using PHP ICS Parser https://github.com/u01jmg3/ics-parser to parse up to 33 remote URL's. The Parser intermittently fails parsing some of these URL's.

The actual exception error details returned by PHP ICS are:

> exception 'Exception' with message 'The file path or URL 'admin.vrbo.com/icalendar/…; does not exist.

Here's my code:

```
foreach($ical_props_arr as $row) {  
    $property_title=$row['title'];  
    $import_url=$row['ical_import_url'];
    try {                       
        $ical = new ICal($import_url, array(
            'defaultSpan'           => 2,     // Default value
            'defaultTimeZone'       => 'UTC',
            'defaultWeekStart'      => 'MO',  // Default value
            'disableCharacterReplacement' => false, // Default value
            'skipRecurrence'              => false, // Default value
            'useTimeZoneWithRRules'       => false, // Default value
        ));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {       
        $error.='An Error Occurred importing: '.$import_url."\n";       
        $error.=$property_title." Import ICAL URL, appears to be Bad!!\n\n";        
    }

}
```

All of the URL's are confirmed good.
Could this be a PHP timing issue, calling the multiple URL's and not waiting for the remote server to respond quick enough?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any errors that might point us in one direction or another? Or are we just supposed to play 20 questions?

Comment: The actual exception error details returned by PHP ICS are:

 exception 'Exception' with message 'The file path or URL      'http://admin.vrbo.com/icalendar/4b6575ac2f5846c5bab17237acebaf50.ics' does not exist.

As stated above all of the URL's are confirmed good.